# Regex to keep the last 4 characters of a string of unknown length using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to use a regular expression to keep the last 4 characters of a string. I don't know the length of the string so I need to start at the end and count backwards. The program is written in c#.

Below are two example strings:

- `840057`
- `1002945`

I need the result to be (last 4 characters):

- `0057`
- `2945`

My original line of code used Regex.Replace but I could not find a regex to work as you can see in the comments below.

```
replacementVal = Regex.Replace(replacementVal, wildcard.Regex, wildcard.RegexReplaceBy);
```

I switched my code to use Regex.Match and then the regex `(?s)[0-9]{4}$` worked perfectly (see below):

```
replacementVal = Regex.Replace(replacementVal, wildcard.Regex, wildcard.RegexReplaceBy);
```

However using Regex.Match breaks other regular expressions that I use, for example I use `^(.).*` to retrieve the first letter of a name. This works when using Regex.Replace but fails when using Regex.Match.

My code is below, note the original line containing Regex.Replace is commented out.

Why does Regex.Match work with one expression and Regex.Replace work with another?

```
      /// Replaces a wildcard in a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="str">The string for which to replace the wildcards</param>
        /// <param name="row">The DataRow in which the string exists</param>
        /// <param name="wildcard">The wildcard to replace</param>
        /// <returns>The string with the wildcard replaced</returns>
        private static string ReplaceWildcardInString(string str, DataRow row, Wildcard wildcard)
        {
            // If the string is null or empty, return it as is
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                return str;

            // This will hold the replacement value
            var replacementVal = string.Empty;

            // If the replacement column value is not empty
            if (!row.IsDBNullOrNull(wildcard.ReplaceByColumnName))
            {
                // Convert its value to string
                replacementVal = row[wildcard.ReplaceByColumnName].ToString();

                // Apply wildcard regex if given
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wildcard.Regex) && wildcard.RegexReplaceBy != null)
                    //replacementVal = Regex.Replace(replacementVal, wildcard.Regex, wildcard.RegexReplaceBy);
                    replacementVal = Regex.Match(replacementVal, wildcard.Regex).Value;
            }

            // Replace all wildcards with the replacement value (case insensitive)
            var wildcardPattern = Regex.Escape(string.Format("%{0}%", wildcard.Name));
            str = Regex.Replace(str, wildcardPattern, replacementVal, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // Return the new string
            return str;
        }
```

Many thank, I appreciate the help.

Comment: and if the string isnt 4 chars long?

Comment: this would work /....$/

Comment: The string is at least 6 characters, sorry I should have said that.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? You have `replacementVal = Regex.Replace(replacementVal, wildcard.Regex, wildcard.RegexReplaceBy);` twice and as the line commented out. What are you referring to by these? 

Also, is it working with `Regex.Replace` commented out and `Regex.Match` works? If so, do you want to use `Regex.Replace` instead of `Regex.Match`?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to clarify the question. The original code was using Regex.Replace which meant the regex ^(.).* worked to retrieve the first letter of the string but I couldn't get any regex to work that left me with the last 4 digits of a string, that was until I changed to using Regex.Match which then allowed (?s)[0-9]{4}$ to work.

Comment: Right, so do you just want to know what will work with Regex  replace? The title of your question says Regex to get the last 4, so is the issue resolved?

Comment: Could you also provide some examples of what this line would evaluate to? `replacementVal = row[wildcard.ReplaceByColumnName].ToString()`

Comment: Looks like the answer from @WiktorStribiżew may be what you are looking for. That is along the lines of what I was thinking anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`Regex.Replace` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) replaces all non-overlapping substrings that match a regular expression pattern with a specified replacement.

The [`Regex.Match` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the regular expression.

So, when you have a string like `1002945`, and you want to get exactly 4 digits from the end, you may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace("1002945", @".*([0-9]{4})$", "$1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

or

```
var matchResult = Regex.Match("1002945", @"[0-9]{4}$");
if (matchResult.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Value);
}
```

When you replace you must match the whole string, match and *capture* only the last four characters that are digits and assert the regex index is at the end of the string (`$`). Note the use of [`RegexOptions.Singleline` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Singleline) allows `.` to match newline char, which it does not match by default. The replacement string should be `$1`, the replacement backreference to the first capturing group that captures the digits.

When you use `Regex.Match("1002945", @"[0-9]{4}$").Value`, you *match* the 4 digits that are followed with either the end of string or a newline and end of string (it is because `$` matches like that, if you do not want to allow a match before a newline and end of string, use `\z` manchor). When the match is obtained, you may check if it was a success or failure using [`matchResult.Success`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success(v=vs.110).aspx), and if there was a match, get the `matchResult.Value`. You no longer need `RegexOptions.Singleline` since there is no `.` in the regex.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. All is now working well. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
.*(?=.{4})$
```

will match everything up to the four last characters of the string. If you replace that match with `String.Empty`, only those four characters remain.

If the string contains fewer than four characters, they will remain in the string because the regex won't match at all so there is nothing to replace.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but when use .{4}$ I am left with 100 from 1002945 not the last 4 digits.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. How do you call your regex capture?

Comment: By the way, his answer is certainly the best

Comment: Your question was unclear - we all interpreted it as "I want to match the last four characters of the string". You want to match everything but the last four characters and replace them with the empty string. Please be specific when writing a question :)

Comment: @user1226884 this is exactly what Tim was saying. `.*(?=.{4})$` captures the 100 in 1002945. Then when you replace it with `""` you're left with 2945.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use regex for that purpose.

```
string MyLast4Characters = MyString.Substring(((MyString.Length >= 4) ? (MyString.Length - 4) : (0)));
```

That part `((MyString.Length >= 4) ? (4) : (0))` is made to check if the original string is longer or equal to 4 characters, then it will return the lasts 4 characters, else the whole string

Comment: In this situation, I need to use regex, unfortunately. I appreciate the code snippet though.

Answer (score 1):

If this has to be regex, I think you want:
`.{4}(?=\s|$)`

But I agree that regex probably is not the best solution here.

A breakdown:

`.  : any character
{4}  : exacty four times
(?=  : followed by
\s  : white space
|  : or
$  : a line ending
)  : end the followed by section`

Comment: When use .{4}(?=\s|$) I am left with 100 from 1002945, not the last 4 digits, there maybe something wrong in my implementation.

Comment: If you look here: https://regex101.com/r/IDMkzM/5 it seems like this works properly. If you are using `Regex.Replace` you are probably left with '100' because it *replaced* the matched portion (2945) @user1226884

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is something with your `RegexOptions`. In my example I use `SingleLine` mode (`(?s)`) and multi-line string:

```
static void RegexTest()
{
    string str = "i am long string\r\nwith the number 1002945";
    string pattern = @"(?s)[0-9]{4}$"; // or @"(?s).{4}$"
    string num = Regex.Match(str, pattern).Value;
}
```

Comment: Inside `(?s)[0-9]{4}$`, `(?s)` is redundant. The pattern has no dot. See my answer where I explain a bit what `RegexOptions.Singleline` (or its inline `(?s)` version) does.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Regex.Match` method.
It matches only what you need.

You can use it one of two ways.

```
string str = "asdf 12345";
if (str.Length > 4)
{
    // Abbreviated ..
    Console.WriteLine( "{0}", Regex.Match(str, @"(?s).{5}$").Value );

    // Verbose ...
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?s).{5}$");
    str = rx.Match(str).Value;
    Console.WriteLine( "{0}", str );
}
else {} // Do something else
```

Output

```
12345
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try and use is `Reverse()` for this purpose

Eg:-

```
string input = "1002945";
string rev = new string(input.Reverse().ToArray());
string res = null;

Match match = Regex.Match(rev, @"\d{4}");
if (match != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
{
   res = new string(match.Value.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

output:-

```
2945
```

[Dot.fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1eHxdb)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Regex.Match as much as possible with the matching groups :

```
string str = "Hello :) 1002945";
string pattern = @"(.).*(\d{4})$";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    string firstChar = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string lastNumber = match.Groups[2].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("First character : " + firstChar);
    Console.WriteLine("Last number : " + lastNumber);
}
```

Output :

```
First character : H
Last number : 2945
```